# in powershell, is it safe to use -Global parameter with import-module cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

Can there be any case when it may lead to security holes or consequences.
I am using this sqlserver module (sql server feature pack) was going out of scope when I was executing import-module sqlserver from inside an ps module. so now I was thinking of putting global in places where I am importing any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely safe to use it. There is no harm in using that. If you are using Powershell remoting then make sure you are enabling the PSRemoting for the required servers only. Apart from administrator, recommended is to use some Service User which has the permission to do remoting . Still if you are concerned about SQL Attacks. There is a powershell toolkit which can do certain stuff. Go through the blog for details - [PowerUp Sql](https://blog.netspi.com/powerupsql-powershell-toolkit-attacking-sql-server/)

Other vulnerabilities are SQL Injections and all which are not because of PS module.  - [Payload Execution](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/mssql/mssql_payload)

Hope it helps

Comment: OK... gotta !! feels like safe enough to me. :)